# Legend colour not matching the graph colour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted the data and the legend color is different from the graph.

```py
for row in Survey2.values.tolist():
    values = row[1:] + [row[1]]
    plt.polar(angles, values, 'o-', linewidth=0.5, label=row[0])
    plt.fill(angles, values, alpha=0.25)

    
# Representation of the spider graph
plt.legend(Survey2["createdAt"], 
            loc=4, 
            fontsize=7)
            
plt.title('PHQ-9,GAD-7 and Likert Scale over the study period', size=12, y=1.07)
plt.thetagrids(angles * 180 / np.pi, labels)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.show()
```

[image: Spider plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show only certain items in legend Python Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680981/show-only-certain-items-in-legend-python-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting two elements per row:

1. `plt.polar(...`  the points
2. `plt.fill(...`  the shading

So when you add your legend, you get two items per row of data: one for the points, and one for the fill. And the legend **is** the same colour as your plot. There's just only 3 entries for the legend, but 6 curves

You can avoid this by adding `label='_nolegend_'` to your `plt.fill(` as answered in a similar question: [Show only certain items in legend Python Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680981/show-only-certain-items-in-legend-python-matplotlib)

Also, if you add a label when creating the curves (with `label=row[0]`), why do you add new labels `Survey2["createdAt"]` when creating the legend? This will overwrite the ones given before

Comment: Perfect. The problem solved